# Disabling win 10 "please wait" blue screen when loading into kiosk mode

Tags: uwp, windows-10, kiosk-mode

I have an UWP app on assigned access, now the app loads well, no problems.

However just before the app loads, The windows please wait blue screen always appears, I was wondering if there is a way to disable it or if it's due to something else ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you set the splant screen image?

Comment: @lindexi sorry, splant screen image?

Comment: It can show when the user opens the app.

Comment: in that case no, I have not, I just set the background image.

Comment: Can you try to use the Image replace the background image?